# StateFlow only works from launch but not from repeatOnLifecycle

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-stateflow

By the docs, I should [never collect the flow from launch or launchIn](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow#stateflow), but if I try to change my code to be executed from inside the `repeatOnLifecycle` it is just being ignored.

This is the code I'm using right now in my `Fragment`:

```
  private fun observeUI() {
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            launch {
                viewModel.uiState.flowWithLifecycle(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle)
                    .collect { uiState ->
                        uiState.error?.let { showErrorAlert(it)}
                        uiState.success?.let { handleSuccessState(it) }
                        handleLoadingState(uiState.isLoading)
                    }
            }
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                scanner.barcode.collect { handleScannedBarcode(it) }
            }
        }
    }
```

The function is called from `onViewCreated` and works as have to.

But if I try to refactor the function by moving the UI collect in `repeatOnLifecycle` that will stop working.

What I'm trying to do is this, and I've yet tried to use `CREATED` instead of `STARTED`:

```
private fun observeUI() {
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            viewModel.uiState.flowWithLifecycle(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle)
                .collect { uiState ->
                    uiState.error?.let { showErrorAlert(it)}
                    uiState.success?.let { handleSuccessState(it) }
                    handleLoadingState(uiState.isLoading)
                }
            scanner.barcode.collect { handleScannedBarcode(it) }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you moved `viewModel.uiState...collect` out of its own child `launch` block, so it's no longer running in parallel with the `scanner.barcode.collect` code. They're running sequentially, but `collect` doesn't return until a Flow is complete. Likely your Flow is infinite. It definitely is if it's a SharedFlow or StateFlow.

These need to be in separate coroutines. You can wrap all but the last of your `collect` calls in `launch { }`, or you can wrap them all for symmetry.

```
private fun observeUI() {
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            launch {
                viewModel.uiState
                    .collect { uiState ->
                        uiState.error?.let { showErrorAlert(it)}
                        uiState.success?.let { handleSuccessState(it) }
                        handleLoadingState(uiState.isLoading)
                }
            }
            launch { 
                scanner.barcode.collect { handleScannedBarcode(it) } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Edit: the format I like to use to avoid deeply indented code:

```
private fun observeUI() {
    viewModel.uiState
        .onEach { uiState ->
            uiState.error?.let { showErrorAlert(it)}
            uiState.success?.let { handleSuccessState(it) }
            handleLoadingState(uiState.isLoading)
        }
        .flowWithLifecycle(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
        .launchIn(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope)

    scanner.barcode
        .onEach { handleScannedBarcode(it) }
        .flowWithLifecycle(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
        .launchIn(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope)
}
```

I actually use an extension function to combine the last two operators since there's some redundancy there.

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.launchWithLifecycleOwner(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner, state: Lifecycle.State): Job =
    flowWithLifecycle(lifecycleOwner.lifecycle, state).launchIn(lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope)
```

Comment: Awesome explanation, I've managed to keep it in separate coroutines instead of wrapping it out :)

Comment: I also missed that you had a `flowWithLifecycle` in there. That's redundant to using `repeatOnLifecycle`. Actually, if you use `flowWithLifecycle`, it's perfectly fine to use `launchIn`.

Comment: So is it equivalent using flowWithLifecycle or it's better anyway to use a separate coroutine like [here](https://i.gyazo.com/b66ff3d4c4f23be096bd3d89f6389a92.png)

Comment: Any way you do it, you're creating at least two coroutines. They might be children of a shared coroutine, or they could both be base level coroutines. I prefer `flowWithLifecycle` followed immediately by `launchIn` and then I never call `launch`. I just have independent coroutines (no shared parent). Then there's a lot less code indention going on.

Comment: Is it possible to have an example of how would you manage it with independent coroutines and `launchIn`?

Comment: I just updated the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253344/discussion-between-nicetomytyuk-and-tenfour04).